# Ubuntu 20.10 stuck at initramfs after update from 20.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, 20.10, initramfs

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10. Some messages at the end of the update were showing errors mentioning Python 3.8 (maybe it was python scripts failing), but since it suggested to reboot, I did that and now I'm stuck in (initramfs).

If I type `exit` in the BusyBox terminal no errors are shown.

If I type `blkid` I see my two crypto_LUKS drives listed (one SSD, one nvme). The SSD is usually decrypted when I type a password, and the second drive is decrypted by the first drive.

Any ideas on how to get back to work?

Update: I rebooted in recovery mode. Then it asked me for the encryption password and went a bit further. It says there is an `UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY` in `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`. I'll see how to run fsck.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the way I solved this was:

1. Reboot and hold down the shift key to show the grub menu.
2. Choose the latest kernel in recovery mode
3. Enter the disk decryption key (if the disk is encrypted).
4. It failed to boot, complaining about `UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY` in `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root` so I ran `fsck /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`.
5. It scanned that partition and offered to repair and delete hundreds of items. After pressing `y` to accept a few dozen times I pressed `a` to accept all.
6. Many pages of repaired elements were shown. Scary, but after that it did boot succesfully.

I suspect those errors were already there from a recent power loss on the computer, but only became apparent when updating the OS.

Comment: FSCK also worked for me, thanks! I was running Kubuntu 20.04 from the hard disk as I had 100 times before. I attempted to run FSCK at the BusyBox prompt but failed. After reading up on FSCK at linuxhandbook.com I ended up booting to a live USB and running "sudo fsck /dev/sda3" from a terminal window.